# Why is an alert() call causing my event to be fired a second time?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working through [this tutorial](https://recaffeinate.co/book/).  I came to the part where I add an event handler for check boxes.  I had some trouble with this, so I put in alert() calls so I could see that the script was being executed.  I also have calls to Console.WriteLine() in my controller to report when a box has successfully been processed and when it failed.

When I have the alert() call in the markCompleted() function, the message appears twice.  And in the console window from which the project is being run, I first see a report of success and then a report of failure.  It appears that when the alert() call is present, the check box's click event is being fired twice.  Why is that?  When I remove the alert() call, I only get one message in the console window and the operation succeeds.

Here's the JavaScript the tutorial told me to put in:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Wire up all of the checkboxes to run markComnpleted()
    //alert("Document ready function");
    $('.done-checkbox').on('click', function (e) {
        markCompleted(e.target);
    });
});

function markCompleted(checkbox) {
    alert("Mark completed function.");
    checkbox.disabled = true;
    var row = checkbox.closest('tr');
    $(row).addClass('done');
    var form = checkbox.closest('form');
    form.submit();
}
```

And here is my controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using AspNetCoreTodo.Services;
using AspNetCoreTodo.Models;

namespace AspNetCoreTodo.Controllers
{
    public class ToDoController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IToDoItemService _toDoItemService;

        public ToDoController(IToDoItemService toDoItemService)
        {
            _toDoItemService = toDoItemService;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            // Get to-do items from database
            var items = await _toDoItemService.GetIncompleteItemsAsync();

            // Put items into a model
            var model = new ToDoViewModel()
            {
                Items = items
            };

            // Render view using the model
            return View(model);
        }

        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddItem(ToDoItem newItem)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            var successful = await _toDoItemService.AddItemAsync(newItem);
            if (!successful)
            {
                return BadRequest("Could not add item.");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> MarkDone(Guid id)
        {
            if (id == Guid.Empty)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received invalid or empty Guid");
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            bool successful = await _toDoItemService.MarkDoneAsync(id);
            if (!successful)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to mark item as done.");
                return BadRequest("Could not mark item as done.");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Item marked done.");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the code from the service:

```
    public async Task<bool> MarkDoneAsync(Guid id)
    {
        var item = await _context.Items
                                 .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                                 .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
        if (item == null)
            return false;

        item.IsDone = true;

        int saveResult = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return saveResult == 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be either of these two issues:
1. You have included both min.js and js and thus it’s binding the event twice. To rule this out use unbind on the click before adding, in which case it should happen once.
2. If this doesn’t help, your event might be propagating to the parent element, you want to try e.PreventDefault() before markcompleted is being called to rule this one out.